# C program chasing and I can't find the mistake

Tags: c, crash

I just started learning programing and I'm having issues with my C code. The idea is to create a squared array sized [m][m] and fill the lateral and one diagonal spaces with 'n' (the user input determine the value of 'm' and 'n'), and then fill the rest of the spaces with numbers following a pattern. But every time it starts to fill the spaces it just crashes without pointing any warning or error.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int M[100][100] = {}, l, c;


int ImpMat(int m)
{
    int l, c;
    for(l = 0; l < m; l++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(c = 0; c < m; c++)
            printf("%i ", M[l][c]);
    }
}

int Matriz(int m, int n)
{
    int l, c;
    for(l = 0; l < m; l++)
    {       
        for(c = 0; c < m; c++)
        {
            if(c == 0 || c == m - 1 || c + l == m - 1)
                M[l][c] = n;
                    
                else
                    M[l][c] = 0;
                
        }
    }
}



int NumMatI(int m)
{
    int l, c, p, q;
    for(l = 2; l < m; l++)
        for(c = m -2; c >= 1; c++)
        {
            p = l - 1;
            q = c + 1;
            if(l + c > m - 1)
                M[l][c] = M[p][c] + M[p][q];
        }
}



int main()
{
    int m, n;
    printf("Type the value of 'm': ");
    scanf("%i", &m);
    printf("Type the value of 'n': ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    Matriz(m, n);
    NumMatI(m);
    ImpMat(m);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The function 'ImpMat' just prints the array, the 'Matriz' creates the array (the size is limited to 100) and 'NumMatI' is where it tries to fill the array.

I already realised the function 'NumMatI' is the one crashing the program, but can't find what is causing it.

I'm using Dev-C++.

Answer (score 0):

In `for(c = m -2; m >= 1; c++)`, the comparison should involve `c` somehow.

Comment: Thanks, it seens that I missed that, but it is still crashing.

Comment: So your fix was wrong, the one you won't show to anybody?

Comment: I corrected the ´´´ for(c = m -2; m >= 1; c++)´´´, but I didn't figured out why it's still crashing

Comment: So you'd like someone to help debug code that is different (somehow) from what you posted?

Comment: The only thing changed from the code I posted is the ` for(c = m - 2; m>= 1; c++ ` to ` for(c = m - 2; c >= 1; c++ ` I still can't find what is crashing it.

Comment: If `c >= 1` is true initially, how is it ever going to become false if you are *increasing* `c`?

Comment: Well, I'm kinda embarassed now. Changed that `c++` to `c--` and it works now. I'm deffinitely learning to use a debugger. Thanks for all your help and your patience